# Data loaded to MySQL via python disappears

Tags: python, mysql

I've looked around to see whether anyone had this problem but looks like not! Basically my problem is as follows:

- I try loading data into MYSQL db using the MySQLdb library for python
- I seem to succeed, since I'm able to retrieve the items I loaded within the same python instance
- ONce the python code is run and closed, when I try to retrieve the data either by running a query in MySQL workbench or by running a python code in command prompt, I cannot retrieve the data..

So in summary, I do load the data in, but the moment I close the python instance, the data seems to disappear..

To try to isolate the problem later, I placed a time.sleep(60) line into my code, so that once the python code loads the data, I can go and try retrieving the data from MYSQL workbench using queries, but I still cant..

I thought perhaps I'm saving data into different instances, but I checked things like "port" etc. and they are identical!..

I've spent 4-5 hours trying to figure out, but starting to lose hope.. Help much apperciated.. Please find below my code:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","password","mydb")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
data = cursor.fetchone()
print data

cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "+ "filepath/file.txt" +" INTO TABLE addata FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'")
data = cursor.fetchall()
print data ###At this point data displays warnings etc
cursor.execute("select * from addata")
data = cursor.fetchmany(10)
print data ###Here I can see that the data is loaded

time.sleep(60) ##Here while the code is sleeping I go to mysql workbench and try the query "select * from addata".. It returns nothing:(
```

Comment: Do you commit your changes?

Comment: Did you try to execute your `LOAD DATA ...` statement directly in MySQLWorkbench or in mysql? Also please show a few lines from your file.

Comment: Thanks guys! The problem indeed was that I didnt commit my changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost certainly need to commit the data after you have loaded it.

If your program exits without committing the data, the DB will roll back your transaction, on the assumption that something has gone wrong.

You may be able to set autocommit as part of your connection request, otherwise you should call 'commit()' via your cursor object.